# Work Efficiency Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Pascal and Rascal are two workers, working together so they can complete a given task in $10$ hours.

If Pascal works for $2.5$ hours and Rascal works for $8.5$ hours, then half of the work will be completed.

> How many hours would it take Pascal to complete the work alone?

What I understood: I can only think of calculating the efficiency of Pascal and Rascal which is $\frac{100}{10}=10$, if we let the efficiency of Pascal be $x$ and of Rascal be $10-x$.

Now we know that

Effiency $\times$ (Time taken) $=$ work done:

$x\times 2.5+(10-x)\times 8.5=50$

($50$, since half the work is completed)

But it is not giving me the right answer.

Comment: maybe look at the partial work and see how long it would take to complete it given that rate instead.

Comment: What is your answer? $120/7$ hrs?

Answer (score 0):

We can see that they complete a $100 \%$ of the job in $2(2.5) \ hours+ 2(8.5) \ hours = 22 \ hours$ when they work $5 \ hours$ and $17 \ hours$ respectively.

Now that's an efficiency that's $\frac{5 + 17}{10}$ times lower than when they complete it in $10 \ hours$.

If we assume that they work the same amount of time during the $10 \ hours$, and that the work done is proportional to the amount of hours they've worked, then Pascal works $\frac{17}{5}$ times faster than Rascal.

If we want to reduce the $22 \ hours$ it takes to complete the $100 \%$ to just $10 \ hours$ instead, we need to reduce the number of hours Rascal work and add those hours to Pascal (the more efficient of the two).

So we have the $5 \ hours $ of Pascal, then we add a certain number of hours to him $x$, we then have the $17 \ hours$ of Rascal, and we remove $\frac{17}{5}$ number of hours more than $x$ from him (because he is that many times less efficient, so one hour for Pascal is $\frac{17}{5}$ or $3.4$ hours work for Rascal). This then must equal $10 \ hours$. We now just need to evalute for $x$ to see how many hours we must add to Pascal and remove from Rascal to get a $100 \%$ from them working 10 hours. Solve the following:

$$(5 + x) + (17-3.4x) = 10$$
$$x = \frac{12}{2.4} = 5$$

So we need to add $5 \ hours$ to Pascal and remove $17 \ hours$ from Rascal, that's the only way "they" can complete it in $10 \ hours$.

If I understood/interpreted the question correctly we clearly see that in this case Pascal has to do all the work, therefore he completes the task by himself in $10 \ hours$.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading the question differently.  The info tells us that in 10 hours, P and R can complete the task.  10/P + 10/R = 1

Next we learn that 2.5/P + 8.5/R = .5, so 5/P + 17/R = 1.

Since we want to solve for P, let's multiply equation 1 by 17, and get 170/P + 170/R = 17.  Equation 2 becomes 50/P + 170/R = 10.  Subtracting, we get 120/P = 7, or P = 120/7, or 17 1/7 hours

Comment: What are $P$ and $R$?